# ABAC Permissions don't work the same for read and write

Tags: faunadb

I'm currently checking out FaunaDB creating a sample Goal tracker (todo!) application. Using graphQL, I have created the schema as:

```
type Goal {
  title: String!
  completed: Boolean!
  owner: User!
}

type User {
  name: String!
  username: String! @unique
}

input GoalInput {
  title: String!
  completed: Boolean!
}
```

I would like to set the ABAC permissions as:

1. Logged in user can view Goals created by themselves.
2. Logged user can edit only Goals created by themselves.

The permissions for role has been set as:

```
{
   resource: Collection("Goal"),
   actions: {
     read: Query(
       Lambda("goalRef", Equals(Select(["data", "owner"], Get(Var("goalRef"))), Identity()))
     ),
     write: Query(
       Lambda("goalRef", Equals(Select(["data", "owner"], Get(Var("goalRef"))), Identity()))
     )
   }
}
```

While the `read` part works well, the `write` part, not so much. `updateGoal` (mutation which is automatically created by FaunaDB) keeps throwing the insufficient permissions error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uploading your provided schema, here is the `GoalInput` generated:

```
input GoalInput {
  title: String!
  completed: Boolean!
}
```

If you cannot create new goals with the `owner` field, then you cannot query them -- `owner` will be `null`

Try to update your schema to include goals field for the user, in order to get the one-to-many relation you are looking for.  ([fauna docs](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/graphql/relations#one2many))

```
type User {
  name: String!
  username: String! @unique
  goals: [Goal] @relation
}
```

Then make sure every time you create a new Goal, you set the owner to yourself.

#### Alternate using functions

You could create a custom mutation to `createGoalForMe` which would automatically set the owner field as you.

Make sure that you give `call` privileges to the new function.

#### Check Permissions

The write permission lambda receives both a newData and oldData as arguments.

```js
/*...*/
{
  resource: Collection("Goal"),
  actions: {
    /*...*/
    write: Query(
      Lambda(
        ["oldData", "newData"],
        And(
          Equals(Identity(), Select(["data", "owner"], Var("oldData"))),
          Equals(
            Select(["data", "owner"], Var("oldData")),
            Select(["data", "owner"], Var("newData"))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  },
  /*...*/
}
/*...*/
```

So change `"goalRef"` to `["oldData", "newData"]` and I think you should have it.

Comment: As seen in the schema `Goal` field has the `owner` field, it's just the `GoalInput` type that does not. This is intentional so that user does not supply an owner, that has to be implicit

Comment: Then you need to create a user-defined function that assigns Identity to owner field.  This will not happen automatically.  If you inspect any created Goals using the built in createGoal mutation, then I suspect you will find there is no value to owner field, which I think is likely why you cannot perform subsequent write actions.

Comment: I do have a custom user defined function defined which puts the `owner` into the record. This is why the `read` permission works, that would have failed without the owner

Comment: I reviewed my role definitions again and I realized that the arguments you pass to the lambda are not correct.  The write action receives 2 arguments.